# How to shift multisite database from localhost to server?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

i have tried to shift my files, database from localhost to online server,while try to access the website error came like "establishing error in database connection". i have changed domain url in "wp-config" file also.i am new one in multisite wordpress website.

Comment: double-check database host, username and password

Comment: @simone i have checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many hosted MySQL instances don't allow clients to connect remotely. You may need to add your IP address into some form of Remote MySQL option if your host provides it. For example, if you use cPanel, there is a 'Remote MySQL' option on there.

Alternatively, you could attempt to export your databases and import them to your remote database using a package such as PHPMyAdmin; if you don't have this available on localhost, you could also do a MySQL dump to a .sql file using the command line like so:

```
mysqldump -u LocalUsername -p LocalPassword LocalDatabase > theFileToExport.sql
```